# ¿Por qué a los partidos Madrid-Barça se les llama "clásicos"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, españa, sustantivos, adjetivos, deportes

No paramos de leer y escuchar que a los partidos de fútbol entre el Read Madrid y el FC Barcelona se les llama "el clásico". Pero ¿por qué? Miremos las definiciones de dicha palabra:

> **[clásico, ca](https://dle.rae.es/cl%C3%A1sico)**
>
> Del lat. *classĭcus*.
>
> 1. adj. Dicho de un período de tiempo: De mayor plenitud de una cultura, de una civilización, de una manifestación artística o cultural, etc.
> 2. adj. Dicho de un autor, de una obra, de un género, etc.: Que pertenece al período clásico. Apl. a un autor o a una obra, u. t. c. s. m. *Esa película es un clásico del cine.*
> 3. adj. Dicho de un autor o de una obra: Que se tiene por modelo digno de imitación en cualquier arte o ciencia. U. t. c. s. m.
> 4. adj. Perteneciente o relativo al momento histórico de una ciencia en el que se establecen teorías y modelos que son la base de su desarrollo posterior.
> 5. adj. Dicho de un autor, de una obra, de un género, etc.: Que pertenece a la literatura o al arte de la Antigüedad griega y romana. Apl. a pers., u. t. c. s. m.
> 6. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a la Antigüedad griega y romana.
> 7. adj. Dicho de la música y de otras artes relacionadas con ella: De tradición culta.
> 8. adj. Que no se aparta de lo tradicional, de las reglas establecidas por la costumbre y el uso. *Un traje de corte clásico.* Apl. a pers., u. t. c. s. Apl. a cosa, u. t. c. s. m.
> 9. adj. Típico, característico. *Actúa con el comportamiento clásico de un profesor.*
> 10. m. Arg., Ur. y Ven. Competición hípica de importancia que se celebra anualmente.

No tengo claro a qué acepción se refiere la denominación de "clásico" para estos partidos. Podría ser la 3, pero me parecería presuntuoso que a dichos partidos se los llamara así por ser el "modelo" a seguir por los demás equipos. Viendo la acepción 10, de uso en determinados países de Hispanoamérica, parece que se denomina así a ciertos eventos que tienen lugar anualmente, pero cualquier partido de liga entre dos equipos cualesquiera (al menos, entre los que habitualmente están en primera división) es un evento que sucede con la misma periodicidad.

Así pues, y desde el punto de vista lingüístico más que deportivo, ¿por qué se llama "clásicos" a los Madrid-Barça?

Comment: Nota que se exportó también la palabra al menos al alemán [(*Der Klassiker*)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Klassiker) y al frances aunque en este ultimo caso, la ortografía varía:  [*le classico*, *le clasico* o *le classique*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Classique).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En Argentina se le llama "clásico" a cualquier partido de fútbol entre dos equipos que sean importantes en su contexto (generalmente de Primera División), y "superclásico" a los partidos River Plate-Boca Juniors, de manera que el uso es internacional.

Mi opinión es que la idea de *clásico* en estos casos es de uso metafórico basado en las definiciones 1, 2, 3 y 8 (que están estrechamente emparentadas). Se trata de partidos entre equipos **antiguos**, de un deporte **tradicional** en el país (el fútbol); los partidos, por existir estos equipos desde hace tanto tiempo, son también una tradición con sus propias reglas, y además se supone que demuestran el mejor fútbol de los mejores equipos del lugar, siendo un **modelo digno de imitación** para los equipos menores y para quienes aspiran a dar un espectáculo deportivo.

El fútbol en nuestros países se presta bastante a toda esta mística, especialmente la parte de la antigüedad. En el caso de Argentina *clásico* es una palabra tan repetida que ya se ha extendido a otros deportes (como el rugby). La definición 10, por el contrario, no me resulta familiar.

Comment: El clásico del hipódromo de Buenos Aires es el Gran Premio Carlos Pellegrini (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gran_Premio_Carlos_Pellegrini).

Comment: Definition 10 is possibly borrowed from the English where certain flat horse races are classics.

Answer (score 1):

En principio el uso parece haberse aplicado **como sinónimo de la voz inglesa *Derbi*** para las principales carreras de caballos. Ese uso propio (adoptado por el turf en Argentina, Uruguay y Venezuela) se refleja en la acepción número décima que la RAE consigna para la palabra **clásico**  (véase también la historia, mencionada por @Gustavson, sobre esta de nombrar la carrera principal de Argentina, el   [Gran Premio Carlos Pellegrini](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gran_Premio_Carlos_Pellegrini) en el hipódromo de Buenos Aires)

> [Derbi](https://dle.rae.es/derbi) 
>   1. m. Competición hípica, especialmente aquella que se celebra anualmente y en la que corren ejemplares de pura sangre de tres años de edad.
>   2. m. Encuentro, por lo común futbolístico, entre dos equipos cuyos seguidores mantienen constante rivalidad, casi siempre por motivos regionales o localistas.

Derbi es un evento (mayormente anual), de una especial importancia en el mundo hípico en el que compiten ejemplares de 3 años de edad ([en el pico de sus rendimientos](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjP-pT2kZ_mAhUXLbkGHeIZBHYQFjACegQIDBAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov%2Fpmc%2Farticles%2FPMC4013968%2F&usg=AOvVaw3YIT-a-SyBz_ojDfGyFeuy) físicos)

No es por lo tanto extraño que la denominación del principal acontecimiento del turf  se hiciera extensiva al fútbol, —el deporte más popular en Sudamérica— *aplicado a los ´partidos de mayor carga emocional, es decir los encuentros notablemente especiales debido a rivalidades locales acentuadas.

Mi interpretación, es que la palabra se aplicó  siguiendo  la acepción número 9 señalada en el diccionario de la RAE

> [Clásico](https://dle.rae.es/cl%C3%A1sico) 
>   9. adj. Típico, [*característico*](https://dle.rae.es/caracter%C3%ADstico?m=form).

aludiendo al sentido de lo que tiene `una cualidad que da carácter o sirve para distinguir a alguien o algo de sus semejantes.` Así las disputas entre rivales acérrimos tiene distinción de ser algo muy esperado por contrincantes sectarios, lo que los dota de un voltaje emocional propio y de una intensidad deportiva diferente a las del resto de los partidos, (* en muchas disciplinas*, ver [fuente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cl%C3%A1sico_deportivo))

El empleo del término en España (sutituyendo a *derbi* [provendría así](https://www.abc.es/deportes/futbol/20150320/abci-oigenes-clasico-barcelona-madrid-201503191929.html) del uso sudamericano en la designación de los partidos de fútbol de interés central, alimentadas por una tradición y una rivalidad acentuada por el carácter vecinal (la mayoría de los "clásicos" se establecen entre equipos de la misma localidad)

Answer (score 0):

Un "clásico" del futbol soccer es esencialmente lo que en inglés se conoce como *derby*, un partido entre equipos vistos popularmente como rivales eternos.

Los motivos por los que nace la rivalidad son siempre distintos, pero generalmente nacen por motivo de ser los dos equipos nacionales vistos popularmente como líderes (el Boca vs. River argentino), el equipo de la capital contra el de la segunda ciudad (Chivas vs. América en México, el primero en Guadalajara y el segundo en el DF), los dos principales equipos locales (Celtic vs. Rangers en Glasgow, Escocia o Chivas vs. Atlas en Guadalajara, México), o en partidos internacionales, por motivos geopolíticos o históricos (México vs. Estados Unidos o el Francia vs. Algeria).